# Unlink Namespace Dev Hub

Tags: namespace, 2gp, dev-hub, 2gp-ama

Obviously you can link a namespace to a Dev Hub, but is it possible to unlink a namespace from a Dev Hub and link it to a new one?

Comment: I don't believe that you can, but perhaps someone else knows better.

Comment: Given that the documentation does not appear to answer this question, the answer appears to be "no," or at least "not without partner support." You should contact partner support for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you can unlink namespaces. But you can link 1 namespace to multiple Dev Hubs.